# What's the best practice to do "stable paging" in OData?

Tags: odata

In the comment of this post ([Problem with WCF Data Service (OData), SetEntitySetPageSize and custom operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708850/problem-with-wcf-data-service-odata-setentitysetpagesize-and-custom-operation)), it mentioned “OData stable paging”.

I am quite new to OData, and trying to get stable paging in OData query.

By "stable paging", I mean there is an OData database in which new entries are constantly being created, I wanted the paging are not interrupted by the new data creation in the database.

For example, if I get the first page by `$top=100`, then get second page by `$top=100&$skip=100`, then the third page by `$top=100&$skip=200`, in which page size is 100. However, because the database is changing, the data I have skipped may not necessarily be the same data I retrieved from previous requests.

Just like the graph example shows data sorting by **entry creation time**, the first request and the second request:

[image]

I wonder what's the best way to do "Stable Paging"?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use "add/append" not use "insert"?

Comment: @SamXu, The graph is sorted by entry creation time, so there are always something new in an updated query. Sorry I forgot to add this info in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution follows this post's recommendation - "Paging Through Results" by Markus Winand:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

It discussed general solutions to stable paging, although it's not OData specific, it works for my scenario.