# WCF Data Services with Entity Framework with View that contains Xml

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-5, odata, wcf-data-services

We have a SQL server View that contains some XML fields.
We created a DBContext using Entity Framework (v5) Database first.
We added a WCF Data Service and assigned it to the DBContext like:

```
       public class ProductsDBSvc : DataService<ProductsDBEntities>
       {
         config.UseVerboseErrors = true;

         config.SetEntitySetPageSize("vw_Release", 100);
         config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("vw_Release", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
       }
```

Using a browser we make this call http://localhost:60606/Products/vw_Release but it returns the below error:

```
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,         Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,     RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
</m:stacktrace>
</m:internalexception>
```

The Error means that we cannot use the XML column in the order by clause and this is a SQL Server error.
While we never asked for an order by in the query.

So we activated the SQL Profiler and we found out the following info:
1- OData WCF Services with Entity Framework referring to a view (rather than a table) sends a SQL Statement that includes order by for each column like this:

```
  SELECT 
  [vw_Release].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [vw_Release].[TypeNameXml] AS [TypeNameXml], 
  [vw_Release].[StatusNameXml] AS [StatusNameXml], 
  [vw_Release].[Created] AS [Created], 
  [vw_Release].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
  FROM [dbo].[vw_Release] AS [vw_Release]) AS [Extent1]
  )  AS [Project1]
  ORDER BY [Project1].[Created] ASC, 
  [Project1].[ID] ASC, [Project1].[Modified] ASC,
  [Project1].[StatusNameXml] ASC, [Project1].[TypeNameXml] ASC
```

2- Getting the same information but just reading from a table instead of a view sends:

```
  SELECT 
  [Release].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [Release].[TypeNameXml] AS [TypeNameXml], 
  [Release].[StatusNameXml] AS [StatusNameXml], 
  [Release].[Created] AS [Created], 
  [Release].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
  FROM [dbo].[Release] AS [vw_Release]) AS [Extent1]
  ORDER BY [Project1].[Created] ASC, 
  [Extent1].[ID] ASC
```

All what we did is out of the box functionality of everything, and can be easily reproduced. Is there a way around to tell the WCF Data Service not to include order by for all columns?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the Config.SetEntityPage size, can you try without setting that and see what happens.

[Problem with WCF Data Service (OData), SetEntitySetPageSize and custom operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708850/problem-with-wcf-data-service-odata-setentitysetpagesize-and-custom-operation)